# ServiceStack Service Gateway throws AggregateException instead of WebServiceException

Tags: exception, servicestack

I'm switching to using ServiceGateway to execute requests from within my ASP.net controller. Whereas before I could just wrap the call in a Try Catch block with catch (WebServiceException ex), now the exception is thrown as AggregateException with innerException of WebServiceException.

```
 try
  {
    var request = new GetRequest();
    var response = HostContext.AppHost.GetServiceGateway(HostContext.GetCurrentRequest()).Send(request);
    //within above call the validator throws exception
    ...
  }
  catch (WebServiceException ex)
  {
    // no longer reaches here

    if (ex.ResponseStatus.ErrorCode == "404")
      return HttpNotFound();
    throw;
  }
  catch (AggregateException ex)
  {
    // reaches here
  }
```

Exception Stack Trace immediately after exception is thrown

```
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ServiceStack.InProcessServiceGateway.ExecSync[TResponse](Object request)
   at ServiceStack.InProcessServiceGateway.Send[TResponse](Object requestDto)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceGatewayExtensions.Send[TResponse](IServiceGateway client, IReturn`1 request)
   at Web.MT.Controllers.User.UserController.List(String categoryHandle, Int32 pageNumber) in C:\Dev\...
```

Before I have to go and refactor a load of code... is this the expected behaviour? Am I just doing it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Whenever an async method is called behind the scenes it will throw an AggregateException. Can you please update your question showing the code you're using as well as the full Exception StackTrace.

Comment: Are you calling this from a classic (.NET Framework) ASP.NET MVC Controller?

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET controller, on .net Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this behavior, I've added a [TestGateway Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/6581f1e8d450831e6b50d14a919cfb087d1dae44) that throws a Not Found Exception within a classic ASP.NET MVC Controller but it still only throws a `WebServiceException`.

#### ServiceStack Service

```
public class TestGateway : IReturn<TestGatewayResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestGatewayResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class TestGatewayService : Service
{
    public object Any(TestGateway request) =>
        throw HttpError.NotFound("NotFound");
}
```

#### Gateway in MVC Controller

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    try
    {
        var request = new TestGateway {Name = "MVC"};
        var gateway = HostContext.AppHost.GetServiceGateway(HostContext.GetCurrentRequest());
        var response = gateway.Send(request);
        //within above call the validator throws exception
    }
    catch (WebServiceException ex)
    {
        // no longer reaches here
        if (ex.ResponseStatus.ErrorCode == "NotFound")
            return HttpNotFound();
        throw;
    }

    return View(GetViewModel("Contact"));
}
```

Which gets caught by the `WebServiceException` handler and returns `HttpNotFound()`.

I can't really recommend anything other than upgrading to the latest ServiceStack if not already, otherwise if you can post a link to a stand-alone repro on GitHub I can investigate further.